# Background image memory size

Tags: android, memory-management

So I got this background image for my activity. Its a 480x800 png.
It has a gradient in it, so there is danger of banding, that's why I made it 99% opaque to force the best color mode.

On my device, and even on a HTC magic this is no problem.

However, on the default 1.6 emulator, I get out of memory errors. What to do?
The background is set in code with:

```
bgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baby_pink_solid);
```

Setting the max VM heap to 192 and device ram size to 256 does not seem to be a solution.

Comment: that looks like an imageview in the background, rather that an image as background. why do you use an imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the Bitmap in code, and then set it via `setImageBitmap()`. If you get an OOM when you are decoding the Bitmap in code, then this is why you are getting it from `setImageResource()`.

I have found that Bitmaps are a tricky thing to handle on Android, and you have to be careful when using them!

Also check out @Sadeshkumar Periyasamy's answer, this is useful for decoding Bitmaps or larger sizes for devices which do not have as much power as todays devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to scale any bitmap:

```
 public class ImageScale 
 {
/**
 * Decodes the path of the image to Bitmap Image.
 * @param imagePath : path of the image.
 * @return Bitmap image.
 */
 public Bitmap decodeImage(String imagePath)
 {  
     Bitmap bitmap=null;
     try
     {

         File file=new File(imagePath);
         BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

         BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),null,o);
         final int REQUIRED_SIZE=200;
         int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;

         int scale=1;
         while(true)
         {
             if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
             break;
             width_tmp/=2;
             height_tmp/=2;
             scale*=2;  
         }  

         BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();

         options.inSampleSize=scale;
         bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);

     }  
     catch(Exception e) 
     {  
         bitmap = null;
     }      
     return bitmap; 
 }

 /**
  * Resizes the given Bitmap to Given size.
  * @param bm : Bitmap to resize.
  * @param newHeight : Height to resize.
  * @param newWidth : Width to resize.
  * @return Resized Bitmap.
  */
 public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) 
 {

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
    try
    {
        if(bm!=null)
        {
            int width = bm.getWidth();
            int height = bm.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            // create a matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            // recreate the new Bitmap
resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix,       true);
 // resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        resizedBitmap = null;
    }

    return resizedBitmap;
} 

 }
```